# Change focus of activities in android

Tags: android

I am using a dialog themed activity in android to show a popup from a application context. The dialog has a transparent theme, but the issue is that I want the underlying activity to have focus and not the popup though the popup must be visble. How do I achieve this in android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use a Fragment and just make it look like a popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can not switch focus between activities. There's only one activity "on focus" at the time, and is the one that is being displayed at that point. The transparent background doesn't mean you can access the activity below.

If i don't get it wrong, you want to be able to interact with the activity's controls while having a "Dialog" on the screen. Any sort of Dialog class from Android will not help, since they take the focus away. Not really sure about PopupWindow, but i'm guessing will be the same thing as the documentation says ["that appears on top of the current activity."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

You are going to have to create a custom dialog using a RelativeLayout/FrameLayout within your activity.

Comment: But even if I create the custom dialog using relative layout , when I pop it up wont the underlying elements lose focus and the popup be in focus or am I mistaken here

Comment: Your parent view should be a relative or frame layout, not the dialog itself. So it will as easy as adding a new View on top of the rest. You will have all the UI elements accessible, and you can request focus or interact with any of them

Comment: I am using a relative layout in the dialog themed activity and then popping it up. Although I am able to control the underlying elements , that is because I have added  flag FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL the background activity still dims and appears to lose focus. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: You are using a new activity, period. That activity will stay on top of the previous one no matter what. You can not accomplish what you want launching a new activity. The only way of doing it is using a View within your activity layout, and display it or hide it accordingly

Comment: The problem is that I am calling the dialog from a broadcast reciever. There is no way I can popup a dialog without calling a new activity since calling a dialog requires an Activity context and I only have an application context

Comment: Make the Activity register/unregister the Broadcast receiver. If the broadcast receiver lifecycle is different than the activity's, then you have to create a new Broadcast receiver within the activity, and send a new broadcast event from your original receiver, to the new one. The display/hide view logic should be inside the broadcast receiver bounded to the activity, which has access to the activity context

Comment: I am using a broadcast receiver within my android manifest file since the lifecycle is different. But if I create a new broadcast receiver within the activity then the popup will only show when the activity is running which is not what I want. Basically I want to show an overlay over the incoming call screen without losing the focus of the call screen. And even if I create it from the activity , the activity will anyway take the focus away and I want the focus to be the incoming call screen